Inline-flex not working when flex wrap is causing wrapping
In my snippet below you can see that I have two inline elements: first a descriptive label, and then an inline-flex container.
What I wish is for my layout to look like it does in my picture:

However, as you can see in my snippet, as soon as the flex items start wrapping, they cause the flex box to somehow become a block element instead which is very confusing to me. I made the container in my snippet resizeable so you switch between the flex box wrapping and not wrapping and you can see how the flex box remains an inline element as long as it is not wrapping, but becomes a block element as soon as it wraps.
Before Answering: The simple solution here is to make the label part of the flex box, however, for this particular project I cannot/do not wish to do that for reasons.
I would understand if there is no solution to my problem and this is just yet another limitation of CSS! I in that case I`ll accept an answer that explains why this is happening because it is very confusing to me.


.container {
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.flex-item {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #ccc;
}
.text {
  display: inline;
  background: #ccc;
}
<div class="container">
  <span>Some inline text:</span>
  <span class="flex">
    <span class="flex-item">Item 1</span>
    <span class="flex-item">Item 2</span>
    <span class="flex-item">Item 3</span>
    <span class="flex-item">Item 4</span>
  </span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <span>Some inline text:</span>
  <span class="text">Some inline text behaving like a propper inline element should behave</span>
</div>




From experimenting some more I believe the problem is that inline-flex is in fact not an inline element but rather an inline-block element. I guess inline-block-flex didnt sound as cool.

Flexbox is not a magic tool for all the situations. You don't need it here.


.container {
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
.flex {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.flex-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 0 .25rem .5rem;
  background: #ccc;
}
<div class="container">
  <span>Some inline text:</span>
  <span class="flex">
    <span class="flex-item">Item 1</span>
    <span class="flex-item">Item 2</span>
    <span class="flex-item">Item 3</span>
    <span class="flex-item">Item 4</span>
  </span>
</div>




You don't even need the inline-block.

well there definitely is a difference using inline and inline-flex here because when substituting the gap property with the margins you also get margins on the outsides of elements instead of just between them which can cause issues. You can even see an example of this in the snippet where the start of the second row is not aligned with the start of the label

@MichaelBenjamin I need it for the vertical padding and margin

Yes, of course. I meant you don't need it for the items to wrap correctly. Wasn't focusing on the non-essential styles. Perhaps I should have been more clear.
